# Determining Max() value in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Excel equation

```
=IF(AB9>=MAX($AB$11:$AB$1048576)-7,"Past 7 years","")
```

Basically, I've found out that if we want to find a maximum value in a column we would have to use the `DMax()` function.

This code does not work and it's probably due to `maxval = DMax("IATA_FY", "Main_Database")`. IATA_FY is a column within the Main_Database query. iatafy is the same column as IATA_FY that will be selected in comparison with maxval.

```
Function past7years(iatafy As String) As String

Dim maxval As Integer

maxval = DMax("IATA_FY", "Main_Database")


If iatafy >= maxval - 7 Then
    past7years = "Past 7 years"

    Else: past7years = ""

End If

End Function
```

Comment: So you're saying that `DMax("IATA_FY", "Main_Database")` does not work either? If not, what is the error message or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Hi Gord, thanks for answering. The problem with this is that MS Access would hang and not respond after execution. I can't seem to get around this problem

Comment: Is [Main_Database] a local table, a linked Access table, or a linked ODBC table? How many rows are in that table? Does the [IATA_FY] column have an index on it?

Comment: Main_Database is a query with linked tables. It contains a few module functions and has around 150,000 rows. And IATA_FY is generated using a module function. It does not have an index.

Comment: In what context are you using this function? As a (derived) column in another query, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a string with an integer - iatafy should be an integer or other number type shouldn't it?

`Function past7years(iatafy as Integer) As String` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the Dmax to following, worked for me

maxval = DMax("IATA_FY", "Main_Database", "")